# Android How to make back button without Actionbar and Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a theme like this in res/values/style.xml and applied to remove
ActionBar.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionbar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
```

And I made a LinerLayout looks like a ActionBar with title and a button(it will have back function).

I'd like to upload the pictures, but I can't upload them yet.

This is a part of the layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarProductInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/backToMain"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_back_34dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="210dp"
                android:text="Input product information"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I put a back function in the button(id:backToMain)?

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: are you using main layout as relative layout?

Comment: @farhana no, the main layout is Linear Layout

Comment: Simply set click listener on image and call method `onBackpressed()` and then override `onBackpressed()` and set intent to init for switching activity.

Comment: You want to change the activity on custom back, is that all?

Comment: @farhana yes, that's all! thank u it works very well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply bind your id of ImageButton in your java and set clicklistner on that id like this

```
ImageButton back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.backToMain);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for you.

Modify your layout as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ActionBarProductInfo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backToMain"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_back" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Input product information"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include your layout in activity then bind your back button.

```
<include layout="@layout/layout" />
```

put this in activity then

```
ImageButton back1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backToMain);
back1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```